# Camera to check if I'm watching the computer?

Tags: screensaver, camera

Is there a program to do following: I have a webcam on my laptop. I would like that my computer starts a screensaver if I'm not watching my laptop and stop the saver when I'm watching the screen. Is there a program for reading the webcam? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I don't know but it would be funny. Some android smartphones already do.

Answer (score 3):

From the sound of this blog post you can use the project `shantz-locker.sh` to do what you want.

- [shantz webcam autolocker](http://tech.shantanugoel.com/2008/08/11/shantz-webcam-autolocker.html)

The post includes everything you need. The 2 pieces are the use of the [`motion`](http://lavrsen.dk/twiki/bin/view/Motion/DownloadFiles) application which is typically available in most repos such as Fedora and/or Ubuntu, and the shell script that's attached to the above article, [shantz-webcam-locer.zip](http://tech.shantanugoel.com/resources/downloads/shantz-webcam-locker.zip).

**NOTE:** I've also posted the script on [pastebin.com here](http://pastebin.com/BcZxHg2q), in case the original ever goes away.

#### Usage

```
./shantz-locker [-l <LockThreshold>] [-u UnlockThreshold] [-s LockScanInterval] [-t UnlockScanInterval]
```

- `LockThreshold` – Determines the threshold (based on no. of samples sans motion) to lock your PC. Default is 5
- `UnlockThreshold` – Determines the threshold (based on no. of samples with motion) to unlock your PC. Default is 2
- `LockScanInterval` – How soon to check if there is motion when your PC is in unlocked state. Default interval is 5 seconds
- `UnlockScanInterval` – How soon to check if there is motion when your PC is in locked state. Default interval is 2 seconds

The ZIP file contains only 2 files, a sample `motion.conf` file along with the script, `shantz-locker.sh`.

```
$ unzip -l shantz-webcam-locker.zip 
Archive:  shantz-webcam-locker.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  08-10-2008 12:11   shantz-webcam-locker/
    22115  08-10-2008 10:57   shantz-webcam-locker/motion.conf
     2954  08-10-2008 11:32   shantz-webcam-locker/shantz-locker.sh
---------                     -------
    25069                     3 files
```

Comment: woah, very cool @slm. Ok. now, to take yet another step toward a sentient living room...

Comment: Hmm. I tried that but it did not close the saver when I sat down by my computer.

Comment: @noobie Make sure that the command `gnome-screensaver-command` works from a shell. You're likely running into an issue with the commands used by this script to lock/unlock the screensaver.

Comment: I installed the gnome-screensaver but the script still won't unlock the screensaver.