# Is there a way to turn on screen lock when I leave the computer?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, screen-lock

I'm looking for a way to automatically turn on screen lock when I leave my computer, since I easily forget to do it manually. I do have a timer but it's not enough.

I found this old question: [Camera to check if I'm watching the computer?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/154559/236940) but it is very old and does not seem to be very relevant today. It mentions Ubuntu 14.04

I also found this old program https://github.com/ArmanFazylov/desk_away_locker but didn't get it to work, and it have not been updated in four years and seem abandoned.

Another program is https://github.com/tiktaalik-dev/blueproximity which is based on bluetooth. It works by detecting if my phone (or another bluetooth device) is close enough to the computer, but that's not a suitable solution, because then I need to remember taking the phone with me.

Anyone who knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried the first method using the `motion` program? that seems pretty sensible.

Comment: Isn't it enough to just lock the screen after N minutes of inactivity?

Comment: I think the best solution would be to make an effort to remember to lock the screen whenever leaving your computer.

Comment: @terdon No it's not

Comment: How do you want your computer to know that you've left? Bluetooth is an obvious choice, but you've dismissed that idea. A camera could work, but you'll probably need multiple cameras (because if the "presence" camera is always active, you can't use it for video calls). You could probably build some sort of device to detect if you're sitting in a chair using a force sensor or accelerometer or something. Anyway, pick your detection method, and then build a solution around that.

Comment: @larsks I don't really have a preference for exactly how it should be done. But I have a preference against the method requiring me to bring any object away from the desktop. Your objection with the cameras is very valid. But buying an extra camera for this purpose is no problem.

Comment: @larsks that could be solved with a bit of shrugging; "if camera is there but claimed, klutt's probably in a call, so don't lock"

Comment: @MarcusMüller That could work. It's not necessary for this to be 100% fool proof.

Comment: @larsks Or a thermal device that detects the heat of the body.

Comment: I came to this thread hoping to find an answer to the same question. Locking your computer the moment you walk away from your desk (for any time) is a requirement for ISO27001 - handling secure and confidential data.